# How can I improve Java2D performance of TextLayout.draw(..)

Tags: performance, text, java-2d

I'm using the Java2D `TextLayout` class together with a `LineBreakMeasurer` and an `AttributedCharacterIterator` to draw a piece of text into a box. The text is wrapped.

Profiling shows me that the code is very slow. Most of the time is lost in the method `TextLayout.draw(..)`.

Does anyone have a suggestion for speed improvement?

```
    // Get iterator for string
    AttributedCharacterIterator iterator = attribText.getIterator();

    // Create measurer
    LineBreakMeasurer measurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(iterator, context);

    // loop over the lines
    int i = 1;
    while (measurer.getPosition() < iterator.getEndIndex()) {
        // Get line
        TextLayout textLayout = measurer.nextLayout(w);

        // get measurements
        float ascent  = textLayout.getAscent();
        float descent = textLayout.getDescent();
        float leading = textLayout.getLeading();
        float size    = ascent + descent;

        // Move down to baseline
        if( i == 1 ) {
            if( coverType == CoverType.SPINE ) {
                y = (box.height-size)/2;
                y -= (size+leading)*(lines-1)/2;
            } else if( vAlign == Alignment.Center ) {
                y += (h-size)/2-(size+leading)*(lines-1)/2;
            } else if( vAlign == Alignment.Bottom ) {
                y += (h-size) - (size+leading)*(lines-1);
            }
        }
        y += ascent;

        // calculate starting point for alignment
        float paintX = x;
        switch( hAlign ) {
            case Right: {
                paintX = x + w - textLayout.getVisibleAdvance();
                break;
            }
            case Center: {
                paintX = x + (w - textLayout.getVisibleAdvance())/2;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Draw line
        textLayout.draw(g2d, paintX, y);

        // Move down to top of next line
        y += descent + leading;
        i++;
    }
```

The relevant code snippet is shown above. `attribText` is an `AttributtedString` set before. `context` is the `g2d.getFontRenderContext()`.

Comment: Let me add something: The code is running on a fresh Ubuntu 10.04. Not sure why that should make a difference - but I noticed that on an old Windows XP it actually runs a lot faster (similar machine). Unfortunately, the Eclipse profiler doesn't work on the XP machine, so I can't judge if the method itself is still using more resources than the rest or if it is just faster overall.

Comment: Digging a bit deeper, I realized that `TextLayout.draw()` implicitely calls `drawGlyphVector()` which is the time sink. Maybe the real question is: How do I draw word-wrapped text with Java2D avoiding `TextLayout` and using `drawString()` instead?

Comment: You're right! textlayout.draw() will draw the text and not write it; graphics.drawString() will write the text and it's really faster than the textlayout.draw() function. If you have not special attribute for small part of your text, you can call g2d.drawString(str.substring(posA, posB), paintX, y); which will be really faster (I've done this into my application); with posA and posB are measurer.getPosition() juste before and juste after doing measurer.nextLayout(w).

Answer (score 0):

This post is rather old now so I hope you have found a solution that works for your needs.  If you haven't here is something to think about.  You only need to draw the text that is within the visible region.  Since you know the y coordinate of each line it is easy to check to see if the y lies within the bounds of getVisibleRect().  Only painting the text that is necessary greatly improves performance (assuming of course that your text is longer than a single page).

Comment: While what you say is generally right, in my case I was drawing on a canvas that will be a bitmap to be written to disk. I need to draw the whole thing in order to create a meaningful image. And I didn't find anything brilliant yet.